# How I can make GUI of Netbeans look darker?

Tags: gui, eclipse, netbeans

I have sensitive eyes. It is important for me - having everything dark in my monitor. How I can make Netbeans good for my eyes? I work under Linux, Lubuntu. Thank you very much for answers.

Comment: +1 for the coolest Eclipse customization that I've ever seen.

Comment: Thanks - it just version from Software Center (Juno have some problems for visual) and Retta code highlighting. I like Lubuntu because from the box I can make color in system darkens - Eclipse use system palette. Screen shooted  from two monitors - console have full screen of my second monitor. +F11 (full screen) for this two windows and hided bar.

Comment: Link is broken. Could you fix? Preferably post a screenshot here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: dark netbeans 7.4, plugin Dynamic LAF Changer]
Now you can use plugin [**Dynamic LAF Changer**](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/49218/dynamic-look-and-feel-changer), **Dark Look and Feel Themes** (can't find on Netbeans site, but I have this plugin on plugin-menu in Netbeans) and [**ez-on-da-ice**](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40985) (I not test this one).

Tools -> Plugins -> Available plugins

Answer (score 2):

You can install "Dark Nimbus Theme" from Tools - Plugins - Available Plugins.
Not as dark as your eclipse, but perhaps what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't have "theme" or "dark" of "nimbus" in this list of plugins. 84 items, NetBeans version 7.0.4. This software can use system palette?

Comment: I find this plugin on web and install. Numbers of lines on white background - it is not fixable? This plugin - the only one way to make NetBeans darker?

Comment: Can I make NetBeans looks like [this](http://forums.netbeans.org/files/sshot_1_133.png)?

Comment: I fix background for line numbers - in Font and Colors menu.